# Can we use history file for auditing purpose

Tags: shell, monitoring

We have a common testing environment on AIX for all 15-20 persons. There might be chances that somebody deleted the files mistakenly. In such scenarios,  it is very difficult to know who deleted files from a specific location.
I would like to generate a report for that same so that we can trace it. In fact, I am looking for following information : 
< ExecutedCmd>

How can we do that by using shell script ?
Please suggest.

Comment: are you using bash? if so you could `grep -i "<executedcmd>" /home/*/.bash_history`

Comment: Yes, bash. But how i will get an information about follwoing:

Comment: <sshd_id><loginDeails ><DateAndTime><ipAddress:portNumber>< ExecutedCmd>

Comment: In fact i would like to generate a report for auditing purpose and send it to an email id for auditing purpose.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: All users in my team using a generic account therefore it is merely impossible to track who mistakenly detected some files.
In current scenario it is impossible to trace when, what and from where files are deleted by whom.
I appreciate your response regarding this request.
How can we do it by shell script ?

Comment: that would be difficult, i don't wanna say impossible but it might be.  /var/log/wtmp(x) holds login info. .bash_history (depending on verbosity) could tell you time, PID, etc. given a time range (.bash_history) you could match that time with /var/log/wtmp(x) or lastlog (`last`)

Comment: If a user's shell can write to .bash_history, then the that user can also modify or truncate it. They could also simply kill -9 $$ so that the shell doesn't have a chance to write to history on exit.

Answer (score 2):

Accountability can not exist in an environment with only one user account. For this reason and for many others (granular access control, reliable privilege revocation, account termination upon dismissal, etc.), you should **really** set up a separate account for each person.

Further, finding out who deleted a file is not going to solve your problem; the file is gone anyway. If the data is mission-critical, it should be backed up regularly and incrementally. There are many ways to do this. rsync with `--link-dest` is appropriate for large-scale system backups whereas some kind of source control would work better for something like a directory full of text files.